# Why did the Station Inspector become teary?

Tags: character, hugo

In Martin Scorsese's *Hugo*, Hugo pleads with the Station Inspector, saying he didn't know why his father died. Then Georges Méliès comes to claim that Hugo is in his care and then takes him.

Why did the Station Inspector become teary at this moment?